# Assign a list elements with various length to multi variebles in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this

```
lst1 = [1, 4, 5]
lst2 = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

What I am trying to do is given length of a list, assign list elements to variables. For instance, in lst1:

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 4
var3 = 5
```

Here is what I am doing, but since the length of my list can be different, what is the best way to write a function that can do this process for different length of a list.

```
var1, var2, var3 = [lst1[i] for i in range(len(lst1))]
```

Comment: So, do you want to unpack first three items to `var1`,`var2`,`var3`? Does the list have always at minimum 3 elements?

Comment: Why do you need to assign every element of the list to a new var?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes, I want to unpack the items to variables.  The list len is always >= 2.

Comment: You already have access to them by using `lst1[0]`, `lst1[1]`, `lst1[2]` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
lst2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

var1, var2, var3, *_ = lst2
print(var1, var2, var3)
```

Or:

```
var1, var2, var3 = lst2[:3]
print(var1, var2, var3)
```

Both will print:

```
0 1 2
```

---

EDIT: To create a dictionary:

```
lst2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

v = {"var{}".format(i): val for i, val in enumerate(lst2, 1)}

print(v["var1"])
print(v["var2"])
print(v["var3"])
print(v["var4"])
print(v["var5"])
```

Prints:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej. I need to generate the Var names as well. So if the len of lst2 is 5, then I want to generate Var1, Var2, ...,Var5. Similarly, if len is 2, the Var1 and Var2 should be generated.

Comment: @armin Use a dictionary for this task. See my edit.